# MySQL join 2 tables where single value exists in second table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve a list of all computers for a client and need to show whether BitLocker is enabled or not (ON / OFF). Basically I am looking at 2 tables: **Computers** and **BitLocker**

I still need to list all computers, but if a **computer_name** such as **SERVER** exists in both tables, I need to find out if bit locker is enabled in the BitLocker table for one of those drives.

The BitLocker table also has a **date_recorded** column as new records are added on a monthly basis, so I have to make sure I always get the newest records.

I can get the query to list all computers, but the **protection_status** column is totally off. **Only the Server should display ON, nothing else.** Any help is much appreciated.

Here's my Query

```
select bitlocker.protection_status, computers.* from computers 
left join bitlocker on computers.client_id = bitlocker.client_id 
inner join (select protection_status, max(id) maxID from bitlocker where protection_status = "ON") d
where computers.client_id=72;
```

[Here's an SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4f6cbb/1)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of joining with the entire `bitlocker` table, join with a subquery that gets the newest row for each computer.

You should be using `computer_name` as the joining condition between the tables, not `client_id`.

```
SELECT c.*, IFNULL(b.protection_status, 'Off') AS protection_status
FROM computers AS c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT b1.computer_name, b1.protection_status
    FROM bitlocker AS b1
    JOIN (
        SELECT computer_name, MAX(date_recorded) AS maxdate
        FROM bitlocker
        GROUP BY computer_name
    ) AS b2 ON b1.computer_name = b2.computer_name AND b1.date_recorded = b2.maxdate
) AS b ON c.computer_name = b.computer_name
WHERE c.client_id = 72
```

Comment: Hi Barmar. This does work, however, server is listed twice. How can I list SERVER just once with protection_status being ON ?  Thx

Comment: You have two `bitlocker` rows with the same `date_recorded`. Which one is the latest?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I want to retrieve the latest record and if it is On. Either C: or D: or even E: Doean't matter which drive letter as long as the latest date_recorded has On for 
one  drive letter. Hope I explained it correctly. Thanks again

Comment: But there are two latest records in the fiddle. Both records have `date_recorded='2023-04-26'`

Comment: Guess I'll need to filter that out in my code then.correct? Or maybe limit 1?

Comment: You could use the `id` column to select the one with the latest date and latest ID.

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8? This will probably be easier with window functions.

Comment: I'm using Mysql 5.7